# Unable to resolve chef roles with TestKitchen

Tags: chef-infra, test-kitchen

I am trying to just log an attribute from a chef role using TestKitchen
Bellow my configuration:

**roles/myrole.json**

```
{
  "name": "myrole",
  "json_class": "Chef::Role",
  "description": "Example",
  "chef_type": "role",
  "default_attributes": {
    "git_cookbook": {
      "mykey1": "myvalue"
    }
  },
  "run_list": [
    "recipe[git_cookbook]"
  ]
}
```

**git_cookbook**

```
log "Hello World, #{node['mykey1']}" do
  level :info
end

package 'git'
```

**kitchen.yaml**

```
---
driver:
  name: vagrant

provisioner:
  name: chef_zero
  roles_path: ../roles

verifier:
  name: inspec

platforms:
  - name: ubuntu-20.04

suites:
  - name: default
    verifier:
      inspec_tests:
        - test/integration/default
    run_list:
        - role[myrole]
    attributes:
```

**Policyfile.rb**

```
name 'git_cookbook'

default_source :supermarket

run_list 'role[myrole]'

cookbook 'git_cookbook', path: '.'
```

when I run the command: kitchen converge (or kitchen test), the value of mykey1 which "myvalue" is not logged.

```
 ....
 Recipe: git_cookbook::default
 log[Hello World, ] action write 
 ....
```

It seems like TestKitchen is ignoring the role which I specified in both kitchen.yaml and Policyfile.rb, I tried to remove it from one or the other, none of the options worked.

Any idea why? am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `git_cookbook` (recipe), you are referring to the attribute: `node['mykey1']`

Whereas, in the `roles/myrole.json`, the attribute you have effectively defined is:

```ruby
node['git_cookbook']['mykey1']
```

Then in your recipe, you should have:

```ruby
log "Hello World, #{node['git_cookbook']['mykey1']}" do
  level :info
end
```